# reloading different view controller when changing settings in current

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Here's the situation.

A dictionary app. Lets imagine we've searched for some article and opened it in view controller in Tab #1 and then changed the set of active dictionaries with controller in Tab #3, so now we need to get data from other db tables. But in our Tab #1 we've got article opened and if we try to do something with it (4ex go back) it will possibly crash.

So, is there any way to reload view in Tab #1, setting it to default blank screen?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter`, see [NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

In your tab 1's `viewDidLoad`, add the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateView:) name:@"updateTab1" object:nil];
```

and add the following method:

```
- (void)updateView:(NSNotification *)notification {
    /* do your updates here */ 
}
```

In your tab #3, when you want to update tab 1:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateTab1" object:nil];
```